# Set function in Tkinter failed to display correct value

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a calculator and here's part of the code:

```
def _digit_formatting(x):
        numbers = '1234567890.'
        start_idxs = []
        end_idxs = []
        is_start = True
        try:
            for idx, value in enumerate(x):
                if value in numbers and is_start:
                    start_idxs.append(idx)
                    is_start = False
                elif value in numbers and idx == len(x) - 1:
                    end_idxs.append(len(x) - 1)
                elif value in numbers and not is_start:
                    pass
                elif value not in numbers and len(start_idxs) > len(end_idxs):
                    end_idxs.append(idx-1)
                    is_start = True     
        except:
            ...

        if len(start_idxs) > len(end_idxs):
            end_idxs.append(start_idxs[-1])
        start_idxs.reverse()
        end_idxs.reverse()
        x = list(x)

        for idx in range(len(start_idxs)):
            if start_idxs[idx] == end_idxs[idx]:
                num = x[start_idxs[idx]:end_idxs[idx]+1]
            else:
                num = x[start_idxs[idx]:end_idxs[idx]+1]
            num = ''.join(num)
            x = ''.join(x)
            x = x[::-1]
            num = num[::-1]
            x = x.replace(num, '', 1)
            x = list(x)
            x.reverse()
            num = num[::-1]
            temp = f'{int(num):,}'
            x.insert(start_idxs[idx], temp)
        x = ''.join(x)
        return x


    def calculate(sv):
        # This function is called when there's changes in entry box
        
        if self.input_string_var.get() == '':
            self.result_string_var.set('')
    
        # Start
        real_result = self.input_string_var.get().replace(',', '')
        percent_count = self.input_string_var.get().count('%')

        # Formatting input string
        x = _digit_formatting(real_result)
        print(x)
        self.input_string_var.set(x)  
        
        if percent_count != 0:
            numbers = '0123456789.'

            for cnt in range(percent_count):
                    
                percent_idx = real_result.find('%', 0)

                limit_operator = 2
                percent_number = ''

                for i in range(percent_idx - 1, -1, -1):
                        
                    if real_result[i] not in numbers:
                        limit_operator -= 1
                    if limit_operator == 0:
                        break
                    if limit_operator == 1:
                        if real_result[i] in '*/':
                            percent_number = ''
                            break
                        else:
                            percent_number += real_result[i]

                if percent_number == '':
                    percent_number = '1'
                else:
                    percent_number = percent_number[1:][::-1]

                real_result = list(real_result)
                real_result[percent_idx] = f'/100*{percent_number}'
                real_result = ''.join(real_result)

        else:
            real_result = self.input_string_var.get().replace(',', '')
        try:            
            if eval(real_result) == int(eval(real_result)):
                self.result_string_var.set(f'{int(eval(real_result)):,}')
            else:
                self.result_string_var.set(f'{int(eval(real_result)):,}')
        except:
            None

        if self.input_string_var.get() == '':
            self.result_string_var.set('')
        
    
    # Entry box string variable
    self.input_string_var = tk.StringVar()
    self.input_string_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: calculate(self.input_string_var))
```

There is two functions, first is _digit_formatting which is to format the equation to put comma like thousands, million and billion. The calculate function is called every time there's changes on the input string variable. But when I try to set the string variable to equation after formatting there seems to be a mistake, but if I print the value, it is correct. Example if I enter 1200 the value I printed is 1,200 which is correct but the value on the text box is not correct. Sorry if the code is messy, I'm still learning to make a clean code.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? Right now there is too much code with a lot of `if` and `for` statements. Make a small example that is easy to read.

Comment: I get "1,200" in the entry box as well if I input "1200".

Comment: @acw1668 did you use the variable trace?

Comment: The value is correct if I press the equal button or other arithmetic function button, but it is incorrect if I didn't, although if I print the value, it is correct.

Comment: Yes, I just use your code and add missing parts to make it run.  It is better to provide a [mre] because there may be other parts of your original code that causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your code.
If you can take a look of my example.

```
n = 1234567890
print(f"I have {n:,} Reputations")
```

Result:
I have 1,234,567,890 Reputations